# custome control event in list view android

Tags: android

I have a listview. which is mase by custome control..
and custome control class extends baseadapter class.
one of my custome control is button..
so onclick of that particular button I have to find position of row..
pleas tell me howz it possible

Answer (score 1):

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,
                long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
```

in above code "onItemClick" method by using third parameter we can get the position of the row